# the_excerpt Read More Filter

Tags: excerpt

Currently, I call the_excerpt via traditional means:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But I add a filter in functions.php for a custom "read more" message.

```
// Changing excerpt more
function new_excerpt_more($post) {
    return ' <a class="read_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'read more' . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Here's the problem; I would like to call the_excerpt inside posts as well without any read more type of link being displayed while leaving the_exerpt being used in the actual excerpts unimpacted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the filter where you need it.

Define the filter callback in `functions.php` but don't add the filter...

```
// Changing excerpt more
function new_excerpt_more($post) {
    return ' <a class="read_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'read more' . '</a>';
}
```

In your template file just before you need the custom more link:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

And remove it afterwards

```
remove_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Or make it self-removing...

```
function new_excerpt_more($post) {
    remove_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more'); 
    return ' <a class="read_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'read more' . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  Maybe this is a stupid question, but when I use this code in my single posts it is displaying  [...] after the excerpt; how would I remove that or properly call in the single posts.  I am using your suggested code in my archives for displaying actual excerpts and using the_excerpt in single posts to display the post's excerpt on the post's page.

Comment: That is really your code. I just re-organized it. Are you sure that this code is involved when you get the `[...]`?